# Google app engine does not run local server

Tags: python, google-app-engine

My `helloworld` code doesnt run on google app engine...
I use python 2.7.6 and `google app engine` version 1.8.8.

Here is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/yash/Google/google_appengine/old_dev_appserver.py", line 196, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/home/yash/Google/google_appengine/old_dev_appserver.py", line 192, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/home/yash/Google/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_main.py", line 173, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools import appcfg
  File "/home/yash/Google/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 74, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools import appengine_rpc
  File "/home/yash/Google/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 28, in <module>
    import fancy_urllib
  File "/home/yash/Google/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib/fancy_urllib/__init__.py", line 354, in <module>
    class FancyHTTPSHandler(urllib2.HTTPSHandler):

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPSHandler'</i>
```

Answer (score 1):

well...problem solved...i guess few libraries werent installed...compiled python 5-6 times after each library installation...

the problem wasnt in the GAE...it was the lack of required python modules

m still a noob...

Thanks for your time and help :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have python support for `SSL`.

Try this

```
pip install ssl
```

Read [python-ssl docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssl) for details.

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/ssl_support)

> If you want to use native python ssl, you must enable it using the
>   libraries configuration in your application's app.yaml file where you
>   specify the library name "ssl", as shown here:

```
libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

Does your `app.yaml` contain this?

Comment: yup...done that already following a similar question on stackoverflow...still the same thing

Comment: also...it says ssl is already built-in in python 2.6 or later

Comment: well i inserted it....now it says ImportError: No module named zlib...............btw a naive question...y would a "hello world" program require ssl??

Comment: @user3055413 Well that question should be asked to the programmer :). Google app engine tutorials use `webapp2.RequestHandler` as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Your google appengine environment probably isn't installed properly.  I'd recommend reinstalling the SDK and checking for errors in the installation.

If you're using something like virtualenv, it could be affecting the way your install works.